# There is no dimens.xml in android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio 2.2.2 on my laptop. Then I updated it recently. But when I create an empty project, there is no dimens.xml on the project. Whereas when I used Android Studio 2.2.2 there is a dimens directory (with 2 dimens.xml). What happen to my Android Studio?

Comment: You can create it by yourself in `values` folder.

Comment: So, is my android studio broken?

Comment: Hard to say, but try to update it to the latest version and restart android studio, and create new project. But if it is not there (dimen file) you can just create it, and start working ;)

Comment: If you need a dimens.xml, you can just create one under the res/values folder

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your Android Studio is fine. From 2.3, the default Activity layout templates have a `ConstraintLayout` as their root element with no margins applied to it. In the old templates, this used to be a `RelativeLayout` with its margins set as resource values in `dimens.xml`. Since these values are no longer in the default layout file, an empty `dimens.xml` is not created in the project by default.

If you need a `dimens.xml`, you can just create one under the `res/values` folder with `New -> Values resource file`.

---

For reference, the old default layout that used `dimens` resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.package.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the new default that doesn't:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.package.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: true but there what is the cause of it and how to get it created automatically when the project is created.

Comment: This is just how the new templates are. You have to create `dimens.xml` for yourself from now on.

Comment: Is there any official doc about this?